# Convert code point(unicode) to UTF-16 and print in java

Tags: unicode, utf-16

I am based on this article
https://kishuagarwal.github.io/unicode.html

---

I took for example: [UTF-16 code point 0x1F9F0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f9f0/index.htm)

In hexa:

```
0x1F9F0
```

In binary:

```
0001 1111 1001 1111 0000
```

Fallowing the explanation from article,
should i have some thing like that:

```
1101 10XX XXXX XXXX 1101 11XX XXXX XXXX
```

Which populate from the bits from do code point, give me

binary:

```
1101 1000 0111 1110 1101 1101 1111 0000
```

hexa:

```
\uD87E \uDDF0
```

But in [this page](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f9f0/index.htm)
correct value is:

hexa:

```
\uD83E\uDDF0
```

binary:

```
1101 1000 0011 1110 1101 1101 1111 0000
```

So...

```
      my hexa: \uD87E \uDDF0
 correct hexa: \uD83E \uDDF0
```

I have single bit misplaced, and I cant figure out why...

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: It's difficult to see what you've done wrong if you don't show us your code.

Comment: @guy, @dawood-ibn-kareem there is no code. IF you wanna code, shoud be:

    `static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println(" \uD83E\uDDF0");
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Converting `0x1F9F0` (`0001 1111 1001 1111 0000`)

From the article you posted, we follow the part:

> For the unicode codepoints from U+010000 to U+10FFFF, ...

and the first step, which you probably missed:

> Firstly 0x010000 is subtracted from the code point, giving us a 20-bit number in the range 0x000000 to 0x0FFFFF.

that is, `0x0F9F0` (`0000 1111 1001 1111 0000`)

> UTF-16 divides these range into two buckets 0xD800...0xDBFF and 0xDC00...0xDFFF (let’s call them A and B ) where each bucket has 10 free bits and 6 fixed bits(shown in grey in the image).

or, as you already posted: `1101 10XX XXXX XXXX` and `1101 11XX XXXX XXXX`

> The 20-bit number that we got above after subracting, is now divided into two parts of 10-bit each. The first 10-bits are used to the fill the 10 free bits of A while the remaining 10-bits are used to fill the 10 free bits of B.

resulting in `1101 1000 0011 1110` and `1101 1101 1111 00000` or `0xD83E 0xDDF0` - as expected.

Comment: True, my mistake  was I read wrong `For the unicode codepoints from U+010000 to U+10FFFF` insted I read: `For the unicode codepoints from U+010000 to U+10FFF`,